# Improve a large query with a subquery and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query which takes 8s to run. How would I optimize the below statement?

```
SELECT
       p.id, territory_id, p.platform_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COALESCE(language_of_content_primary_id, base_language_id), ',', IFNULL(languages_of_content_additional, '')) languages,
       p.store_url, allows_free_streaming, requires_paid_subscription, group_concat(sd_retail_price) purchase
FROM
    main_iteminstance i INNER JOIN main_territorypricing p ON p.item_id=i.id
WHERE
    (doesnt_exist_on_store_anymore=0 AND p.store_url IS NOT NULL)
    AND
    (master_id=%s OR tv_series_id IN (SELECT id FROM main_iteminstance WHERE master_id=%s))
GROUP BY
    territory_id, platform_id''', (self.pk, self.pk))
```

Note that the following runs in 0.03s --

```
               WHERE
               (doesnt_exist_on_store_anymore=0 AND p.store_url IS NOT NULL)
               AND
               (master_id=33568)
```

But using the subquery adds the extra 8s --

```
               WHERE
               (doesnt_exist_on_store_anymore=0 AND p.store_url IS NOT NULL)
               AND
               (master_id=%s OR tv_series_id IN (SELECT id FROM main_iteminstance WHERE master_id=%s))
```

For whatever reason, it seems that when I broke this up into two queries it performed much better than one, here is what I now have --

```
tv_series_ids = cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM table WHERE master_id=%s)
```

And the new `WHERE` clause --

```
WHERE
(doesnt_exist_on_store_anymore=0 AND p.store_url IS NOT NULL)
AND
(master_id=%s OR tv_series_id IN %s)
```

Could someone please explain to me why pre-fetching the ids performs so much better than doing a sub-query?

Here are the two execution plans --

[image]

Comment: For clarity, edit your question and qualify all the column names so it is clear where they are coming from.

Comment: Do your tables have any indexes? If those `WHERE` clauses are fairly selective, indexing the filtering columns might be a good place to start. And of course the second is slower. It requires an actual scan, whereas the `master_id = 33568` can use an index to find a *single row* in the table for that column. (It then only has to find the rows that `JOIN` to that single row, which will still be a much smaller set.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see updated question.

Comment: RE your edit: did you examine the plan explanation? Can you provide it?

Comment: @jpmc26 good idea -- please see updated question.

Comment: The two queries are not exactly equivalent. Can you show the plan explanation if you just replace the subquery with the ID list? That said, the subquery version appears to be doing a full table scan instead of leveraging the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the second

```
AND
(master_id=%s OR tv_series_id IN (SELECT id FROM main_iteminstance WHERE master_id=%s))
```

To FROM section with JOIN like this

```
FROM
    main_iteminstance i INNER JOIN main_territorypricing p ON p.item_id=i.id
    INNER JOIN main_iteminstance i2 ON (i.tv_series_id = i2.id OR i.master_id=%s)
WHERE
    (doesnt_exist_on_store_anymore=0 AND p.store_url IS NOT NULL)
```